# A recurrence equation for the number of multiplications in an algorithm for computing powers

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

We were asked the to find the recurrence equation for the number of multiplications for the following algorithm as a function of N. For simiplicity, let $ N = 2^k $ and is a positive integer:

[image]

I understand that the the time for $T_1 = 0$ (Base Case) since there are no multiplications. For the recurrence part

$T_n = 2 + T_\frac{n}{2} +  T_\frac{n}{2} = 2 + 2T_\frac{n}{2} $ because there a 2 recursive calls for every level before N == 1

Thereafter, I proceeded to expand:

$T_n = 2 + 2T_\frac{n}{2} $

$T_n = 2 + 2(2 +T_\frac{n}{2^2}) = 2 + 2^2+ 2T_\frac{n}{2^2}$

...

$T_n = 2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + ... + 2^k + 2^kT_\frac{n}{2^k} $

Since we could assume that $ n = 2^k $, the last term will be 0 since it would be $ T_1 $

Therefore the answer would be:

$T_n = 2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + ... + 2^k $ Which would have k number of terms, which could then simplified to $ T_n = 2^{k+2} - 2$ using Geometric Series.

However, the answer given to me was "There are k + 1 number of terms, which is simplified to $ T_n = 2^{k+1} - 2$

Why is this so ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I assume that this algorithm is only being analysed in order to show how bad it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + ... + 2^k= 2^{k+1} - 2\ne 2^{k+2} - 2$$

Comment: dear me, must have been careless while applying the geometric formula. Thanks for the correction! Will accept this as the answer when it's available :)

Comment: One should check from time to time the formulas one believes one knows, on simple cases, say `2+2^2+2^3=2+4+8=14=16-2=2^4-2` hence `2^(k+1)-2` is promising and `2^(k+2)-2` is impossible.